# Cassandra CQL - get records since 1 before timestamp

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have the following table:

`CREATE TABLE records(
   device_id text, 
   read_time timestamp, 
   data_row text, 
   PRIMARY KEY (device_id, read_time )) 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (read_time DESC);`

I want to get all the records starting with the one before a specific read_time.
Is there a way to do that?
I thought maybe having another field previous_read_time, but it will be hard to 
maintain since I sometime get out of order reads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any CQL statement that does this (filter on a timestamp column PLUS the first record not matching the time filter). But depending on your exact case maybe something like the following would work for you?

For example I will find all records with read_time after `2020-05-14 00:00:01` plus the first one on-or-before `2020-05-14 00:00:01`:

1. Select all records after my chosen time (`2020-05-14 00:00:01`).

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE device_id=? AND read_time > '2020-05-14 00:00:01';
```

2. From the results of the first query, take the record with the read time closest to `2020-05-14 00:00:01`.

```
// Let's say you find records with the following times. 
// The earliest (closest to the filter's time) is 2020-05-14 00:00:55
2020-05-14 00:00:55
2020-05-14 00:00:56
2020-05-14 00:30:55
2020-05-14 13:30:55
```

3. Select again and find the first record which comes before the "closest time to the filter time" you found in step 2:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE device_id=? AND read_time < 2020-05-14 00:00:55 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I will use it for now but will be happy to know of a more efficient way since I'll be doing this a lot (A LOT) of times... 

Thanks!